# How to display WhatsApp DP in the WhatsApp Web intermediate page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chat, whatsapp

I am trying to add a WhatsApp chat option on my website using the following code:

```html
<a href="https://wa.me/+91XXXXXXXXXX/"
        data-action="share/whatsapp/share"
        target="_blank" class="float" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```

When I click on the button, it redirects me to the WhatsApp Web intermediate page but does not show my WhatsApp profile picture.

I have checked some other websites and they show a page like this.

[image: I have checked some other websites and they show a page like this.]

How can I show a page like this? Can someone please help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have change settings>privacy>profile photo to **Everyone**

Comment: the profile photo is already Public

Answer (score 0):

I **removed the "+" symbol from the previous code**, and it is functioning properly. The phone number should now be registered in WhatsApp Business.